# Bootcamp Thunderbolt Ethernet Adapter

Tags: windows, boot-camp

Im running Windows 8.1 on my MBP Retina 2013 via Bootcamp.
Since yesterday, the cable network adapter is missing on the network adapter panel in windows.

I tried to reinstall the "BroadcomEthernet64.exe" Setup from the Bootcamp drivers, but this doesnt help.
Anyone know how i can reinstall the netzwork drivers in Bootcamp?

Answer (score -1):

The Thunderbolt Ethernet Adapter is not hot swappable, which means anytime you interrupt the connection, you will need to reboot with the thunderbolt connected to your Ethernet.  I understand, but have not confirmed, this issue is corrected in the 2015 models.